# How to define path for subfolder

Tags: php, file, path, include, constants

I'm learning PHP and I'm having problems with the definition of the path.

If in the settings.php file located in the main folder I define a constant with the base path of the site to be able to use this constant in the subfolders I must include the file settngs.php precept by "../" as in the following way: ". ./settings.php "

is there any way to define the settings.php path that is also usable in the subfolder files without having to manually add "../" before the file name?

or a way to define constants usable in every file without including the file that contains the constants?

settings.php:

```
// FILE SETTINGS.PHP IN THE MAIN DIRECTORY

define('SITE_URL','http://localhost/');
```

---

admin/index.php:

```
// FILE INDEX.PHP IN THE ADMIN SUBDIRECTORY


include('../settings.php');
<a href="<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>">HOME</a>
```

There is a way to have SITE_URL working without `include('../settings.php')` or there is a way to include "settings.php" in subdirectory without the "../" ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`set_include_path`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) function.

For example:

```php
set_include_path(__DIR__.'/../');
```

Then include file from parent directory

```php
include 'settings.php';
```